# Sitecore WFFM check duplicate email

Tags: c#, sitecore, web-forms-for-marketers

I am developing a form validation action for WFFM, which will not allow people to use same email for submitting multiple entries. So far, the only document I've got is the WFFM v2.3 Ref from Sitecore SDN, which only have few example of how to access submitted data form by form.

I don't know how to select data by using field value. So, my current solution is to retrieve all data from database and check all email fields; which doesn't seem right when putting in scale.

Do you have any code snippet that can help me add GridFilter like email="abc@def.com", if count > 0 definitely the email is duplicated?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of finding the API supporting this very own demand, I found it easier to make a direct connection to the WFFM database and look up for what I want. Thank you for reading this.

Answer (score 0):

The webforms database has 3 tables only. If for example, you want the list of email ids available in the 'Support Form' below:

[image]

Here's the query:

> ```
> SELECT DISTINCT Value FROM [dbo].[Field]
> WHERE FieldId = '5F5643B6-0535-49D8-B3C9-CF8E65A415C0'
> ```

Field Id corresponds to the field GUID of the form:
[image]

Ps. WebForms connections string should be available in App_Config\Include\forms.config.